# How to do an aggregate operation with $cond checking for null values in same array while grouping

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my document,

```
{
  "_id": "58aecaa3758fbff4176db088",
  "actualEndDate": "2017-02-27T00:00:00.000Z",
  "Details": [
    {         
      "projectId": "58a585f6758fbff4176dadb9",
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": "58aecac8758fbff4176db08b",
  "actualEndDate": "2017-03-12T00:00:00.000Z",
  "Details": [
    {         
      "projectId": "58a585f6758fbff4176dadb9",
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": "58aecac8758fbff4176db08c",
  "actualEndDate": null,
  "Details": [
    {         
      "projectId": "58a585f6758fbff4176dadb9",
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to group these and in my query, I need to find `$max` of "actualEndDate" with condition only if all "actualEndDate" fields are not null.

I tried something like this,

```
{ 
    $group: 
           {
              _id: '$Details.projectId',
              actualEndDate: 
                   { 
                     $cond: { 
                             if: { $ne: [ $actualEndDate, null] }, 
                             then: $actualEndDate, else: null
                            }
                   }
            }
}
```

so that I can get the expected result like

```
{
   "projectId": "58a585f6758fbff4176dadb9",
   "actualEndDate": null,
}
```

If the sample does not contain the `{ "_id": "58aecac8758fbff4176db08c" }` record, then I expect the result to have `actualEndDate` as max of other two documents

```
{
   "projectId": "58a585f6758fbff4176dadb9",
   "actualEndDate": "2017-03-12T00:00:00.000Z",
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) your `actualDate` field, [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) your `Details` array and then `$group` taking only the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) date will ensure this is the most recent date:

```
db.data.aggregate([{
    $sort: {
        "actualEndDate": -1
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$Details"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$Details.projectId",
        actualEndDate: {
            $first: "$actualEndDate"
        }
    }
}]);
```

If you want to return a null `date` if at least one date is null for the specified `projectId` the following will do the job :

```
db.data.aggregate([{
    $sort: {
        "actualEndDate": -1
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$Details"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$Details.projectId",
        dates: {
            $push: "$actualEndDate"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        projectId: "$_id",
        actualEndDate: {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    $setIsSubset: [
                        [null], "$dates"
                    ]
                },
                then: null,
                else: { $arrayElemAt: ["$dates", 0] }
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

The idea is to [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) all the dates into a new array and make a projection to return `null` when `null` is spotted inside the array otherwise return the first element of the array (with the values sorted in the first stage)

Comment: Hi here the array is sorted, $first gives the date because null values comes after the date  while sorting.

Comment: i need null for "actualEndDate" if any "actualEndDate" is null